# Better way to deal with Tk's keyboard events mess for numpad keys in Python+tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a tkinter application that responds to individual key presses on the numeric keypad. I find that handling the tk events for the numpad keypresses are a real pain because all platforms that I tried it on result in totally different events (windows, mac, linux), and the documentation I could find is either incomplete or just wrong. My main doc source is http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html

Only Linux seems "sane" and allows you to grab the tk `keysym` name such as "KP_Enter". Windows however requires you to either look at the `keysym_num` OR at the `keycode` depending on if you want to deal with NumLock on/off correctly, and still, can't seem to differentiate between some numpad keys and their normal equivalents (+/+, Enter/Return etc)  OSX then, requires you to look at the `keycode` and those are  totally different once again.

Example, the **'0'** key on the numpad:

- Linux: `event.keysym == 'KP_0'`
- Windows: `event.keysym_num == 65379`
  or when Numlock is enabled: `event.keycode == 96`
- Mac OS:
  `event.keycode == 5374000`

---

*Am I missing something here, or is this really messy like this? Is there a better solution I overlook?*

---

In  my code I bound the keyup/down events on the main window:

```
class NumpadmadnessWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keypress)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keyrelease)
```

And for debugging purposes my event handlers look like this:

```
    def keypress(self, event):
        print(time.time(), "KEYPRESS {char!r} keysym='{keysym}' keycode={keycode} keysym_num={keysym_num} state={state}".format(**vars(event))) 

    def keyrelease(self, event):
        print(time.time(), "KEYPRESS {char!r} keysym='{keysym}' keycode={keycode} keysym_num={keysym_num} state={state}".format(**vars(event)))
```

Full code for a little runnable test application not really relevant I think, but can be found here: https://gist.github.com/irmen/2c9d6bb0afb16b464805410c108a2885

Comment: why are you checking the keysym instead of simply binding to the specific key? If you bind to `<1>`, for example, that binding will fire whether the user uses the keypad or the numeral key on the other part of the board. Do you really need to differentiate between a `1` from the keypad and a `1` from some other part of the keyboard?

Comment: What happens if you try to check one of those attributes on a different OS? For example, trying to examine `keysym` on Windows?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I want to specifically do something different when a numpad key is used as opposed to the equivalent key on the regular part of the keyboard.  More specifically: I want to use the numpad as a joystick simulation

Comment: @user2357112 the problem is that numpad keys can no longer be distinguished from regular keys because they're all folded in to the same keysym, or keycode, or keysym_num, depending on what OS you're on... i.e. the distinguishing attribute of the event is different every time