# Numberpad binding in themed tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to `bind` **numberpad** keys in my **python** program using `themed tkinter` library, but in vain. I looked up the docs on [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm), but there is no mention for binding of num-pad keys. The mentioned event binding includes only for *alphabets*, *number-keys*(above the alphabet keys), *mouse-button*, and many more.

The follwoing code binds number keys placed above the alohabet keys:

```py
>>> Frame.bind("1", callback) # binds Key 1, not num-pad Key 1
```

How do I bind the **number-pad** keys?

Comment: Maybe this would be insightful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53757787/how-to-bind-keys-numbers-on-numpad also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869902/better-way-to-deal-with-tks-keyboard-events-mess-for-numpad-keys-in-pythontkin

Comment: @JasonChia Seems like keypad bindings are a mess, this [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869902/better-way-to-deal-with-tks-keyboard-events-mess-for-numpad-keys-in-pythontkin) query lives for more than 3 years now .

Comment: BTW `"<1>"` is the event code for mouse button-1, not key 1.  It should be `"1"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In this [doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20190515021108id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html).Mentioned:

> For example, the digit 2 on the numeric keypad (key symbol KP_2) and the down arrow on the numeric keypad (key symbol KP_Down) have the same key code (88), but different .keysym_num values (65433 and 65458, respectively).

So you could try to use:

```
Frame.bind("<KP_1>", callback)
```

However, this couldn't work on my PC.Another way is bind all the keys,and check the `keycode` to know whether you pressed num-pad key 1:

```
def callback(e):
    if e.keycode == 97:
        print("you pressed num-pad 1")

Frame.bind("<Key>", callback)
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, **<KP_1>** format of binding currently works well for Linux type OS only.

Comment: Using ```<Key>``` does not work for me, is there any ```import``` needed for using ```keycode```.

Comment: @maddypie You could bind `<Key>` and `print(event)` in the callback, press `1` in the num pad to see the `keycode`.

Comment: I found out that keycode values are also different PCs. The workaround to this problem is by using ```e.char```. It is pretty straightforward: ```if e.char == str(1) #instead of e.keycode == 97```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already by @jizhihoaSAMA:

```py
def callback(e):
    if e.keycode == 97:
        print("you pressed num-pad 1"))
```

Not all systems can guarantee the same keycode values *(keycode for '1' is '97' in Windows and '87' in Linux)*

Thus instead of using `keycode` one can use `char`:

```py
def callback(e):
    if int(e.char) in range(10):
        print(f'you pressed {e.char}')
```

**Note:** *callback* is also invoked when number-keys are pressed (since they have the same *char* value). This might be desirable in some cases.